# What does "membrane" mean? does "triple pulsation" is "a pulsation that happens three times"?

Tags: meaning

What does "membrane" mean? does "triple pulsation" is "a pulsation that happens three times"?

As to the
objectivity of these noises, Crookes says of Miss Kate Fox:
It seems only necessary for her to place her hand on any substance for
loud thuds to be heard in it, like a **triple pulsation**, sometimes loud
enough to be heard several rooms off. In this manner I have heard them
in a living tree—on a sheet of glass—on a stretched iron wire—on a
stretched **membrane**—a tambourine—on the roof of a cab —and on the
floor of a theatre.

good links: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/membrane

Comment: The collocation ***triple pulsation*** has no special idiomatic significance in English, and ***almost all*** [instances of it in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+triple+pulsation%22) are your cited example. I think it's entirely a matter of opinion whether you interpret that word-pair as meaning ***a pulse consisting of three consecutive sounds / tones*** or as ***three consecutive pulses***. Or indeed whether those actually are two "different" sounds. But "membrane" here just means ***for instance, a drum-skin*** (the clue being "tambourine" immediately following).

Comment: Literature is writing. Writing does not always contain repeatable phrasing. Thank goodness for that! Triple winner= a winner who has won three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "membrane" refers to the following word, "tambourine" a kind of percussion musical instrument that consists of a band of metal or wood bent in a circle, with a thin sheet of some material like leather or paper stretched over it that is struck to produce sound. The membrane is the sheet of material.
This definition has a picture:
[Merriam-Webster "tambourine"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tambourine)

Yes, "triple pulsation" probably means a pulse (a thump sound)  repeated three times.